# write data into <input type="file"> using js

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to assign the value of `<input type="file" id="field1">` to `<input type="file" id="field2">`.

I'm having the following code but it is not working as expected:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function test(){
   var field_value = document.getElementById('file1').value;
   document.getElementById('file2').value = field_value;
}
</script>
<body>
  <input type="file" onchange="test()" id="file1"/>
  <input type="file" id="file2"/>
</body>
```

Explanation: When I click on the browse field of file field having `id="file1"` it calls `test()` function.  Variable `field_value` is having the name of the file uploaded. But it is not assigning the value to file field having `id="file2"`.

Answer (score 2):

For security reasons you cannot access the file controls with Javascript (imagine if you could automatically upload any file you want when the user visits a page!)

Having said that, the newest version of Firefox has a new [File API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/File), which might help you for that specific browser. And there are various [File controls](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/number-state.html#file-upload-state) introduced in HTML5, but it will be a long time before you can use them.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot get nor set the value of an `<input type="file" >` in Javascript.

Comment: Actually you *can* get the value, but it's not really the complete path - the only useful part is the "name" part (the tail end of the path).  You're right that it cannot be set, however.

Comment: But if I am getting the value I might be able to set it.